# $scope.$watch on some part of object in array

Tags: angularjs

There is an array as below, which stores a mixture of data and styles in it.

User is able to add, remove or re-order its elements, as well as modify value of elements, so I need to watch it with `$scope.$watch` to do something if it's modified.

However, I don't want to get notified if only its style changes. Is there any better practice to arrange my data, to get notified only if value is changed, thank you.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UmhmWkdjbwwwRX89OcSM?p=preview)

```
[{
  value: 1,
  selected: true,
  width: '100px'
}, {
  value: 2,
  width: '150px'
}, {
  value: 3,
  width: '100px'
}];
```

Comment: Just to confirm a few things: (1) the only property you want to be notified of changing is `value`? (2) should the watcher also ignore any shuffling of the order of the data? (3) watcher definitely preferable to ng-change, etc?

Comment: @JcT (1) There may be a few values I need to get notified (2) The order of array shouldn't be ignored (3) It may not be from `<input>`, so I don't think ng-change is applicable. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to watch only when style changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GAG40qBkD4eq3GbKBMhc?p=preview

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
    return $scope.data.
    map(function(data) {
        return data.width;
    });
}, function(newValue) {
    console.log('Modified width' + newValue);
}, true);
```

I think similarly you will have to create watch on needed attributes.

Source:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/03/26/angularjs-watch-for-changes-in-specific-object-property/

Answer (score 0):

Call `$watch` with `true` as the third argument:

```
 $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
  },true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, changing of `style` will also invoke watcher.

Comment: when change of `style`, compare `newValue[1].width` and `oldValue[1].width`. If not equal,not do anything

Comment: hmm but that can't guarantee that others didn't change.